# Can you achieve the best ending in DS3 without dying once?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I am currently doing my first DS3 playthrough, and I generally try to complete these kinds of games without dying once. So far I am doing fine, but a friend told me that to achieve the best ending it is actually necessary to die.

Can somebody confirm this and give more info on it without too many spoilers?

I only beat the first couple bosses so far and want to keep it a blind playthrough.

Comment: From what I remember, a guy beat the entire game without taking damage from an enemy once, much less die.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as the best ending, all endings are just different.

There are total 4 possible endings in the game, and only one of them:

> Usurpation of Fire

requires you to die multiple times to receive

> Dark Sigils from Yoel of Londor.

You can check all endings details [on wiki (spoilers, obviously)](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Endings)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I guess my friend was talking about the Usurpation of Fire ending. I don't want to go on the wiki, but can you tell me the minimum amount of deahts to get this particular ending?

Comment: @korn55 wiki says 10 deaths. I would suggest not to bother with it: this ending has somewhat complex prerequisites, I don't think it's possible to achieve it on a blind play through as some things are "time sensitive"